# Sharepoint 2010: Web Services Get All Sub-Sites Where User Has Write Permission

Tags: web-services

I have an external application which displays all sub-sites and document libraries where the user has write permissions. At the moment I am using "GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser" to get permissions for each sub-site and "GetListItemChangesSinceToken" to get permissions for each library.

But this is a very time taking process as, if there are 100 sub-sites I need to make a web-service call for each sub-site .i.e., 100 calls. Is there any way to get all the sub-sites and document libraries where the user has Write permission? Or at least any way that I can piggyback all the web-service requests for all the sub-sites in one call.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* Just realised you are performing this task using Web services. Back to the drawing board (I don't have access to delete the post)!

---

I'm not really a developer but this is a fairly common scenario and it sparked my interest. I imagine there is a better way of doing it but this may work:

You could construct a CAML query using the [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms409088.aspx) class to retrieve all lists in the site collection.

To view permissions you could specify the "[IncludeAllUserPermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.includealluserpermissions.aspx)" property in a where clause that defines the SPSiteDataQuery.Query property.

SPSiteDataQuery returns a DataTable object that should contain the lists and permissions assuming the above is correct.

If I get a chance I may give this a try on a test VM, but let me know how you get on.